# Does Django Class Based Views automatically assign form value for templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I use Django 2

This is what my view.py contains

```
class SchoolCreateView(CreateView):
     fields = ("name","principal","location")
     model = models.School
```

The template (html file) used by this view contains the code:

```
form.instance.pk
```

And it works. It returns the correct primary key. I don't understand why.
Why does this work when I have not defined the form object in my view? Is the value of form automatically assigned when using CBVs in Django?

Follow up question. I know that form.instance represents a row in the model but what does form itself represent? My current understanding with forms is that it represents request.POST from views.py (basing my knowledge from function views). But that wouldn't make sense because the client has yet to make a POST request since he is still going to create a data entry which will be posted but is not being posted yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pk is a primary key field, which is `id` by default. if you define other field as primary key, calling pk will return this.

From documentation:

By default, Django gives each model the following field:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is an auto-incrementing primary key.

If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify `primary_key=True` on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.

Each model requires exactly one field to have `primary_key=True` (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

Comment: I understand how pk works when it comes to handling columns in model instances. What I do not understand is how a CBV automatically declares a form for templates. In my templates, I have form.instance.pk. How does the template know the value associated with form (from form.instance.pk) when I did not explicitly declare it in SchoolCreateView?

Comment: When you inherit from `CreateView` and declare model, i.e. `model = models.School`, `{{ form }}` became a type of your model and have model's id field.